# Making the body background responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have been dealing with this issue for a while now, tried to solve it myself but i just can't seam to be able to get to the bottom of it. Basically, I have a background that I use in the body tag. However, as soon as I add text on the background the image gets distorted on mobile devices, pixelated and it kind of zooms in.

This is the css code I use for the body background image:

```
body {
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 70px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots? Of course it will get pixelated if it's too small and you're trying to stretch it over the whole background.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello, the image is not too small. It's 1900 x 1200 pixels.. that's why im confused as to why it gets pixelated and distorted...

Comment: As Lazar and andreas pointed out: Please provide some more info, e.g. screenshots and HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By fixing the image and position the center location on it, the image will center in all your display modes.

```css
html,body{
 height: 100%;
}
body{ 
 background-image:url(http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Yoshi-The-Seal-Kitteh.jpg);
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat:  no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size:  cover;
}
```

Comment: Hello,this worked and everything now appears great! Thank you so much for your help!